# Playframework 2 and manytoone form binding

Tags: java, spring, playframework-2.0, many-to-one

I'm following the example in the Play framework sample computer DB app and have the following models

```
public class Simulation  implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="projection_set_id")
    public ProjectionSet projectionSet;
}

public class ProjectionSet  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;
}
```

In the form, I have the following form helper

```
@helper.select(
          simulationForm("projectionSet.id"),
          options(ProjectionSet.options),
          '_label -> "Team Context",
          '_showConstraints -> false
)
```

The options are defined as

```
public static Map<String,String> options() {
    List<ProjectionSet> projectionSets = ProjectionSet.findAll();
    LinkedHashMap<String,String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    for(ProjectionSet set: projectionSets) {
        options.put(set.id.toString(), set.forDate.toString());
    }
    return options;
}
```

and in the controller I have the following:

```
    Form<Simulation> filledForm = simulationForm.bindFromRequest();
    Logger.debug("form = " + filledForm.toString());
    if(filledForm.hasErrors()) {
        final User user = BaseController.currentUser();
        return badRequest(newSimulation.render(user, filledForm));
    } else {
        Map<String, String> formData = filledForm.data();
        Simulation created = filledForm.get();
        created.create();
        return redirect("/simulations");
    }
```

The exception I'm getting is

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved  transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:   models.simulations.Simulation.projectionSet -> models.baseball.ProjectionSet
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$8.noCascade(CascadingAction.java:380) ~       [hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
```

After placing a breakpoint, the problem appears that the Simulation class I get from bindToRequest, has a ProjectionSet object but all the values within it are null.  I then stepped through the bindToRequest method and what I'm finding is that for the nested binding, ie) projectionSet.id, the spring binder is throwing an exception from within the org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl class in the setPropertyValue method

```
private void setPropertyValue(PropertyTokenHolder tokens, PropertyValue pv) throws BeansException {
```

and in particular, it is throwing a NotWriteablePropertyException when the resolvedDescriptor for the PropertyValue is null.

I'm very new to Spring and it's binding library.  I'm not sure what I can do to get this property to resolve properly.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You taged this question with: "java", "spring", "playframework-2.0", "many-to-many" - it his a mistake "spring" instead of "hibernate"?

Comment: Well the data binding occurs in the org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl class so I thought Spring might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try registering a formatter for `ProjectionSet` class. So that `Form.bindFromRequest()` knows how to convert the id in your submitted form to an actual object. I prefer to define formatters on application level, so that I place them in  [Global](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaGlobal) object.

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
  static {
   play.data.format.Formatters.register(ProjectionSet.class,
                                new Formatters.SimpleFormatter<ProjectionSet>() {
        @Override
        public ProjectionSet parse(String id, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
            ProjectionSet pSet = null;
            try {
                long tmpId = Long.parseLong(id);
                pSet = ProjectionSet.finder.byId(tmpId);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
                //unexpected id
            }
            return pSet;
        }

        @Override
        public String print(ProjectionSet pSet , Locale locale) {
            return pSet.id + "";
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Check out [this page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms) for more on form handling and especially last section for defining a mapping from/to a custom object.

Comment: So I tried this and added in a breakpoint into the Formatter implementation, but it never gets called.  I see that it's now included in the ConversionService but the parse method never gets called.  Do I need to change how I bindFromRequest?  Or should it automatically attempt to bind based on class?

Comment: Well, in your code you haven't given the definiton of `simulationForm` it should be like this `Form<Simulation> form = Form.form(Simulation.class);` A more compact approach for form binding would be `Form<Simulation> filledForm = Form.form(Simulation.class).bindFromRequest();`

Comment: ahh, sorry about that. `private final static Form<Simulation> simulationForm = form(Simulation.class);`
 is how I defined the Form.

Comment: Your form field names should correspond to the property names of underlying object so that binder can correctly work. Therefore changing `simulationForm("projectionSet.id")` in your template to `simulationForm("projectionSet")` should solve your problem.

Comment: i'm glad that i could help.